# Updated the Navigation framework and getting error - "getActionId overrides nothing"

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation, android-safe-args

I have updated the Navigation framework from 2.3.5 to the 2.4.0-alpha01 version. I use it with Safe Args gradle plugin. After update, I started getting `'getActionId' overrides nothing` and `'getArguments' overrides nothing` errors.

I think this is happening because Safe Args is overriding the `actionId` and `arguments` fields of `NavDirections` improperly when generating the Direction classes.

For example, this is what is being generated:

```
 public override fun getActionId(): Int =
        R.id.action_navigation_articles_to_articleReaderFragment
```

This is what should be generated:

```
public override val actionId: Int = R.id.action_navigation_articles_to_articleReaderFragment
```

How can I get the Safe Args to generate proper builder classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out this was a known [bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/188564435) for some time.

And right after a day after I posted this question, [2.4.0-alpha02 Navigation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation#2.4.0-alpha02) was released with a fix for this bug:

> Safe Args no longer crashes when attempting to generate direction
> properties in Kotlin. (Id2416, b/188564435)

Just update to 2.4.0-alpha02 version for a fix.

Comment: latest version - 2.4.0-alpha06

Answer (score 0):

update to 2.5.0-alpha01 version and wrapper-properties distributionUrl -7.0.2-bin.zip for a fix.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).