# “getActionId overrides nothing” after upgrading to navigation version 2.4.0-alpha02

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation

I got this issue after upgrading from version 2.3 to 2.4.0-alpha02.
The new version should contain a [fix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67818994/14969444), but it did not work for me.
For reference, my actions are defined like so:

```
<action
        android:id="@+id/action_from_to_destination"
        app:destination="@id/destination" />
```

Comment: Did you rebuild your project?

Comment: Yes I did @Zain

Comment: Please include where you define your Safe Args Plugin version - this looks like you're still using an old version of the plugin.

Comment: Thank you @ianhanniballake, your answer was spot on as always. I had forgot to upgrade the Safe Args Plugin. Issue resolved

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks to @ianhanniballake, I figured out what the problem was. All androidx.navigation dependencies should have the same version. In my case the Safe Args Plugin was still at version 3.5. Issue resolved by upgrading it to 2.4.0-alpha02.

If anyone ran into the same issue, here is what you need to avoid similar problems in the future:

In **build.gradle** define the following under buildscript:

```
 ext.navigation_version="2.4.0-alpha02"
```

and under dependencies:

```
classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$navigation_version"
```

In **build.gradle (:app)**, under dependencies:

```
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime-ktx:$navigation_version"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$navigation_version"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$navigation_version"
```

Now you only need to change the navigation version one place.